# C# MVC get exactly the same URL string like in browser from server side

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller

I know this is quite easy to get URL in many ways but I have unexpected issues when querying website by DNS, which redirects to a non-default port.

There is a web app working on port 7000 which is accessible by server name or dns:

1. http://MyServer:7000
2. http://MyApp.intranet.net (maps MyServer on port 7000)

This is how users see them in the browser.
So now, how to get exactly the same URL link like in a browser.

**HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri** returns respectively:

1. http://MyServer:7000
2. http://MyApp.intranet.net:7000 (**Port was added, this address doesn't exist!!!**)

**HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString**:

1. http://MyServer:7000
2. http://MyApp.intranet.net:7000 (the same like above)

**HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority**:

1. MyServer:7000
2. MyApp.intranet.net:7000 (the same like above)

**HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host**:

1. MyServer (no port information, returns error)
2. MyApp.intranet.net (that's fine)

I didn't find any property which returns both addresses correctly, as browser user has.

And I don't want to hardcode anything or send this from the client-side.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What about `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl retruns only path without server name and port e.g. for http://MyServer/account/test RawUrl="/account/test"

Comment: Right. If it is not an ajax request then I guess the only way is to get the current URL from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`, otherwise if it is an ajax call then you can get the URL using JS and add to the header.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` results the same like `AbsoluteUri`. That's called by Html.ActionLink`. I can add window.location as parameter but I'm really suprised there is no solution on server side only. Thanks